Sequence in an ArrayFormula creating cumulative sum
UPDATE: I think this cannot be done with SCAN
In the example below, I am introducing the issue with simply adding the rows numbers (1+2+3...). In my original formula, I am using the current row number to power my basis (x^1 + x^2 + x^3...). X would be a constant. Let's say x = 2, then the formulas from below would change to sth like:
=SUM(SEQUENCE(2^ROW()))

and
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SEQUENCE(2^ROW(A1:A5))))

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1spA9Y7ViVvQr7JSWretNcC97w1ozdZRqOKEnvBQIom4/edit?usp=sharing
Hi, I was wondering how to transform the following formula to an array formula:
=SUM(SEQUENCE(ROW()))

Goal:

No helper column
Arrayformula
No scripts

If dragged over 5 rows, it creates cumulative sum:
1
3
6
10
15

(see B1:B5 in attached link)
Unfortunately, this solution does not work:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SEQUENCE(ROW(A1:A5))))

Why? Sequence requires integer as the first argument and ROW(A1:A5), if placed in an outer ARRAYFORMULA, behaves as an array. Sequence than takes treats this as:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SEQUENCE(ROW(A1))))

...resulting in just one cell filled with number 5 (SUM(1,1,1,1,1))
(see A1 in attached link)
I basically need to keep the outer ARRAYFORMULA, while "de-arraying" the ROW() formula.
Any ideas?
This is just a simplified version of the formula that I created for the purpose of posting here.
My original formula that I'd like to transform to an array formula:
=IF(
    AND(
        ROW() - 1 <= ROUNDDOWN($Q$4 * 12, 0),
        $C$1 = TRUE
    ),
    LAMBDA(
        var,
        IF(
            $P$17 = "Ano",
            (1 - 0.15) * var + 0.15 * ((ROW() - 1) * ($Q$10 + $Q$28 + $Q$29) + ROUNDDOWN((ROW() - 1) / 12, 0) * $P$30),
            var
        )
    )(
        ($Q$10 + $Q$28 + $Q$29) * SUMPRODUCT(($Q$7 / 100 + 1) ^ SEQUENCE(ROW() - 1, 1, 1, 1)) + ROUNDDOWN((ROW() - 1) / 12, 0) * $P$30
    ),
    ""
)


try:
=INDEX(SCAN(0; ROW(A1:A5); LAMBDA(aa; bb; aa+bb)))


or just BYROW it:
=INDEX(BYROW(ROW(A1:A5); LAMBDA(x; SUM(SEQUENCE(2^x)))))





You may try:
=makearray(rows(A1:A5);1;lambda(r;c;sum(sequence(2^r))))



If you need to operate with different arrays of the same size, I suggest you use MAP to do that part. You can set as many arrays as arguments, and then apply the desired operation (in this case, a sum and multiplication*5):
=MAP(I1:I5;makearray(ROWS(A1:A5);1;lambda(r;c;SUM(sequence(2^r))));LAMBDA(a;b;a+5*b))


PS: a second alternative for the sequence part with BYROW:
=BYROW(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A5));LAMBDA(r;SUM(SEQUENCE(2^r))))

